# Spring Boot Security OAuth SSO and Keycloak: Too many redirects while getting user details

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

I'm trying to setup a microservice architecture with a Spring Netflix Zuul Proxy and Keycloak. Because I don't want to start at an old Spring release, I decided to connect Keycloak with the Spring Security OAuth2 library.

The Zuul application got the annotation `@EnableOAUth2Sso` and the mocroservice behind `@EnableResourceServer`. Now, when I'm accessing Zuul with the path to the service, the Keycloak login screen is shown as it should. But after login, I'm getting an `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. Accoring to the Keycloak Log

```
09:57:40,354 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
09:57:40,355 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
09:57:40,355 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: Keycloak 4.0.0.Beta3 (WildFly Core 3.0.8.Final) started in 35495ms - Started 545 of 881 services (604 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
10:04:12,978 WARN  [org.keycloak.services] (default task-40) KC-SERVICES0091: Request is missing scope 'openid' so it's not treated as OIDC, but just pure OAuth2 request.
10:04:23,408 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-49) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:23,485 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-47) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:23,563 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-46) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:23,613 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-51) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:23,689 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-50) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:23,771 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-53) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:23,815 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-52) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:23,888 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-54) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:23,977 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-55) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,090 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-56) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,132 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-57) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,165 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-58) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,197 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-59) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,238 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-60) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,269 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-61) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,330 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-62) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,485 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-2) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,508 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
10:04:24,576 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-63) type=USER_INFO_REQUEST_ERROR, realmId=LIA, clientId=null, userId=null, ipAddress=127.0.0.1, error=invalid_token, auth_method=validate_access_token
```

Spring is not delivering the right information. As the result, Zuul can not get the details about the user

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain user details from token
```

My config is

```
server:
  port: 8762
  session:
    cookie:
      name: PROXYOAUTH2COOKIE

spring:
  application:
    name: zuul-server

eureka:
  instance:
    perferIpAdress: true
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceurl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:1112/eureka

keycloak-client:
  server-url: http://localhost:8080/auth
  realm: LIA

security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: user-systems
      clientSecret: 9a9539b5-f397-49be-be89-086422530648
      accessTokenUri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/realms/${keycloak-client.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/token
      userAuthorizationUri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/realms/${keycloak-client.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/auth
      tokenName: access_token
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      userInfoUri: ${keycloak-client.server-url}/realms/${keycloak-client.realm}/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo
```

As you see I tried a few things like setting the cookie name but nothing helped. The error still exists and I don't know why.

Comment: I have the same issue, how did you manage to solve the issue ?

Comment: Unfortunatly I'm now using my own Spring OAuth2 Server, so I think I didn't solve that. @SlimaneDeb